# Prestashop 1.5.x.x: Last row displays 2 of the products instead of 3

Tags: prestashop

I have a problem regarding a webpage that I´m currently working on. 
The theme that I´m working the site with is gameguru 1.5 and the matter is that on the final row of my product-list, when I get to the bottom of it, there are 2 products appearing instead of 3. 
The relevant code of the source file (product-list.tpl) is this one:

```
{if isset($products)}
<!-- Products list -->
<div id="product_list" class="clear category_list product_list grid row">
    <div class="inner-product-list">
    {foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
        <div class="ajax_block_product {if $smarty.foreach.products.first}first_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.products.last}last_item{/if} {if $smarty.foreach.products.index % 2}alternate_item{else}item{/if} clearfix  col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
```

I´ve tried several things but I´m quite stuck here. 
Finally, I would like to include one product list of the webpage in order to give you a bit more guidance.
http://tutiendadevideojuegos.com/127-ps4-videojuegos-ps4
I would appreciate very much any help.

Thanks,
Orestis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this part

```
{if $smarty.foreach.products.index % 2}alternate_item{else}item{/if}
```

change to

```
{if $smarty.foreach.products.index % 3}alternate_item{else}item{/if}
```

UPD:
to manipulate number of products per page, in backoffice `Preferences -> Products` option "Products per page" put there e.g. 12 and you will have 3 products in all lines + correct values in dropdown.

Comment: No I didn´t actually, and the thing is that when I was uploading the newest file,  the updated products list page wouldn´t show up  at all...
I will try and do that and I'll comment you about it tomorrow.

Comment: I´ve already tried this one but it doesn´t seem to work either. I cleared the cache inside prestashop´s preferences. I also tried to delete anything that would be into the root directory via Filezilla but inside the folder of cache there was nothing but one file named index.php. I´m a bit lost here but thanks for your interest.

Comment: I read your question again, so the issue is only about lat products line on the page, there 2 products instead of 3? How many "items per page" choosed in your case? For 24 items I see 8 lines x3 items, for 20 - 6x3 + 2 items in last line

Comment: Yes that´s correct. The thing is now that we adjusted it via front-office to 24 products per page (8 rows*3 product) so the situation goes like you have mentioned before. But when you for example go to the panel where you can choose between how many products you want to visualize (for example there´s a list that can visualize 10,20,50, the default one). Now there are 4 options 10,20,24,50 and when you firstly enter the store, the layout comes up with 24 listed products. It´s not fixed in its core because the other options are hidden in the panel there but it´s visually correct for the visitor.

Comment: okay, but still trying undestand you want to choose e.g. 20 products per page and have 3 products in all lines including last? Or what the main issue?

Comment: In that case they would be 21 products with 7 rows - 3 products each one so it can´t be in that case. If they would have been 20 products per page every time there would be 2 products in the last row. In other case, if I would change the grid to 4 products per row it would work perfectly but in that case I would need also to change the bootstrap grid files to assure that everything is ok.

Comment: ok, what is you final task/idea? have values in dropdown that are divided by 3  like 12,24,48?

Comment: Yes but I don´t have much of a clue of what is needed to be done. I mean my knowledge on php is pretty limited so any help would be recommended if you have any thoughts on the matter. I surely can understand javascript (basic knowledge) and have an intermediate level of html5 and css3 but  I´m not not familiar with Php.

Comment: It doesn´t work either..It keeps being the same, values on the dropdown are: 10,20,24 and 50. Thanks again though..

Comment: what value do you put there? 12? Do you have any core overrides especiall FrontController?

Comment: also compare content of file /themes/your-theme/nbr-product-page.tpl with default prestashop theme , is it equal?

Comment: Finally solved it. Forgot to post the solution. I went to the document FrontController.php and edited this line: `array((int) Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE'), 12, 24, 36, 50) :` to `array((int) Configuration::get('PS_PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE'), 12, 24, 36,48) :`  Simple as that.

Comment: what core version do you have? by default FrontController have no this line

Comment: The version was 1.5.6 I think. It wasn't any of the 1.6 versions.

Comment: you question has tag "prestashop-1.6" all answers was related with this core version

Comment: Sorry, I got mistaken. It was a version of 1.5x not 1.6x